# Can a non-null view have a null reference for its context in a listener?

Tags: android, android-view, android-context

Assume a code as follows:

```
final View someView = ....;  

// some code  
someView.setOnClickListener(v -> {  
    if(someView == null) return;  
    Context context = someView.getContext();  
    // can context be null at this point?
});
```

Is it possible a view to have a null `Context` at some flow?

Answer (score 0):

My guess: I think context can't be null if View is not null.

Checking the source code of `View.java`, we can see:

```
public class View {

    public View(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public final Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `mContext` is initialized in the constructor and its reference does not change (`mContext` reference is not updated).. It is always pointing to the reference received in the constructor.
Also, `getContext()` is final. So, it can't be overriden ensuring `getContext()` will always execute the code above.

If you try to create a view passing a null pointer (like `View someView = new View(null)`) your app will crash for other reasons... So, `mContext` (and `getContext()`) can't be null if view is not null.